# jsonarray to string conversion

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to convert a JSON array to a string.
I have tried `getJSONArray("name").toString();` but it's not working.
This is my current output `[\"Name Already Exists\"]"`.
I want this output: `Name Already Exists`.

Comment: Without seeing any other code than this one line it's totally unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want `asdf` as result, but get `["asdf"]` ?

Comment: yes you are partial correct, I am getting / also as output..I dont want..expected output is: Name Already Exists.

Comment: Do you have only one string as entry in that array?

Comment: yes only one string

Comment: If you want only the first element in your array, you'll need something like `jsonArray[0].toString()`. If you want the entire array, you need to loop over the array, apply `toString()` to the individual elements, and concatenate the result.

Comment: Show your JSON Array completely

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSONArray like this:

```
[
    "my string"
]
```

Usually, JSONArrays are used - like normal arrays - with multiple entries. You are currently converting the whole JSONArray to a string. The `\` is there because without it, the quotes would terminate that string.

What you want is to get only the first element out of that array. If you know that your array contains only one string, you can do something like

```
String result = myJSONArray.getString(0);
```